# convert join table using rx.net

Tags: linq, join, rx.net

In my database I have a join table to store many to many relationships between a `JobType` and `DocumentType` (simplified description)

#### JobType Table

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int |
| Description | varchar(100) |

#### DocumentType Table

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int |
| Description | varchar(100) |

#### JobTypeDocumentType with the following columns:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int |
| JobType | int |
| DocumentType | int |

I want to retrieve the data from the database and convert the result recordset into an `IObservable<collection<ViewModels>>`.

In the code below, the GetJobDocumentTypes method returns a collection of JobTypeDocumentType POCOs:

```
IObservable<IReadOnlyCollection<JobTypeDocumentType>> dataService.GetJobDocumentTypes(int jobTypeId)` 

The purpose of getJobTypeDocumenTypeViewModels is to transform the returned POCOs into ViewModels:



private IObservable<IEnumerable<JobTypeDocumentTypeViewModel>> getJobTypeDocumenTypeViewModels(JobType jobType)
        {
            var result = dataService.GetJobDocumentTypes(jobType.Id)
                .Select(items => items.Select(jtdt => 
                        dataService.GetById<DocumentType>(jtdt.DocumentType_Id)
                                   .Select(dt => new JobTypeDocumentTypeViewModel(jtdt, jobType, dt))));
            return result;
        }
```

However, I am stuck with result being of type `IObservable<IEnumerable<IObservable<JobTypeDocumentTypeViewModel>>>`

Any help and/or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `SelectMany` in this case:

```cs
var result = dataService.GetJobDocumentTypes(jobType.Id)
    .SelectMany(items => items
        .Select(jtdt => dataService.GetById<DocumentType>(jtdt.DocumentType_Id)
        .Select(dt => new JobTypeDocumentTypeViewModel(jtdt, jobType, dt)))
    );
```

Comment: your code results in IObservable<IObservable<JobTypeDocumentTypeViewModel>> but I am trying to get IObservable<IEnumerable<JobTypeDocumentTypeViewModel>>

Comment: My code just returns IEnumerable. Who converted to IObservable? What is GetJobDocumentTypes?

Comment: the signature is shown in the code:
`IObservable<IReadOnlyCollection<JobTypeDocumentType>> dataService.GetJobDocumentTypes(int jobTypeId)`

It returns a  IObservable<IEnumerable<JobTypeDocumentTypeViewModel>>